# Multiselect attribute not working on frontend

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom multi-select attribute for the product in Magento admin. but in the frontend, it is working the same as a dropdown. It is not working multi-select.

Comment: how you create this attribute? How it not working?

Comment: We have created attribute from Admin side

Comment: please share your code